# Weird White Line appears on buttons in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

I have a critical HTML issue: a weird white line appears on buttons in Internet Explorer.

**Example of Original Mockup -**

[image: Original]

Button HTML -

```
<input type="button" Class="buttonAll" value="Regenerate" onClick="Captcha();"/>

<input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="" class="buttonAll">
```

My UI HTML does not include any **Doctype** and I have a criteria to do only Cosmetic changes.

I tried to Apply CSS in 2 ways:

**Using BG Image -**

[image: using Bg Image]

CSS for the above:

```
background:#92110d url(../images/bg-all-buttons.gif) repeat-x 0 0;
```

**Using CSS Gradient -**

[image: Using CSS Gradient]

CSS:

```
input[type="button"], input[type="submit"], .buttonAll {

    overflow:visible; display:inline-block; cursor:pointer;  
    outline:0px none; width: auto; vertical-align:middle;
    margin:3px 6px 3px 0px; padding:2px 6px; border:1px solid #804240; 

    /*background:#92110d url(../images/bg-all-buttons.gif) repeat-x 0 0;*/

    background: #92110d;    background-repeat:repeat;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f04b47), to(#92110d));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #f04b47, #92110d);
    filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f04b47', endColorstr='#92110d');

    text-align:center; text-transform:capitalize; color:#fdfad9; font-size:11px!important; }
```

Both of the above code works well in FF and Chrome.

Is there is any possibility that it happens due to Events Focus / Active / Blur
I want to know how can I remove this white Line?

Comment: What white line do you mean? The focus border? I do not see a white line.

Comment: can you add an example as to how it should look (show us a chrome example - or give us the html too )

Comment: "My UI HTML does not include any Doctype"...no doctype = quirks mode in IE, which means many things do not look as intended.

Comment: Ya, I agree... Its Quirks mode in IE! But want to find a technical reason , why its Weird...

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove border from input field for example `input[type="button"], input[type="submit"], .buttonAll { border:none;}`

Comment: Worked for me, ensure you have the correct CSS selector for the button and maybe also use `!important`. e.g. `button, .btn { border: none !important; }`

Answer (score 0):

Vipul above code is right. reason is your doctype declaration. because there is two type of document modes 1. strict mode, 2. quirks mode. Quirk mode doesn't support W3C modern standards.

Comment: I agree with you but is there any Javascript which can remove the Focus / take its focus elsewhere rather than on buttons... Or any tag that can give more control...